# How to replace event id with enum?

Tags: c#, enums

I have class that inherits from EventSource:

```
[EventSource(Name = "MyEventSource")]
public sealed class ExceptionHundler : EventSource
{
    public static ExceptionHundler Log = new ExceptionHundler();
    [NonEvent]
    public void WriteLog(Exception exception)
    {
        UnhandledException(exception.Message);
    }

    [Event(601, Channel = EventChannel.Admin, Message = "Unhandled exception occurred. Details: {0}", Keywords = EventKeywords.None, Level = EventLevel.Critical)]
    private void UnhandledException(string exceptionMsg)
    {
        WriteEvent(601, exceptionMsg, Environment.MachineName);
    }
}
```

As you see I'm setting event Id in attribute Event (its 601). Now I want to create enum and use it instead of event Id like :

```
 enum EventType
{
    AppCrashed
}
```

And Event attribute:

```
 [Event(EventType.AppCrashed, Channel = EventChannel.Admin, Message = "Unhandled exception occurred. Details: {0}", Keywords = EventKeywords.None, Level = EventLevel.Critical)]
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: `[Event((int)EventType.AppCrashed` would already work if you don't mind the cast. The constructor really only takes an int. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.tracing.eventattribute.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a static class with public constants:

```
public static class EventType
{
    public const int AppCrashed = 601;
}
```

Not exactly the `enum` solution you want but you [stated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54033600/how-to-replace-event-id-with-enum#comment94904146_54034182) you don't want to cast the enum value every time. Usage would be more or less the same:

```
[Event(EventType.AppCrashed, Channel = EventChannel.Admin, Message = "Unhandled exception occurred. Details: {0}", Keywords = EventKeywords.None, Level = EventLevel.Critical)]
private void UnhandledException(string exceptionMsg)
{
    WriteEvent(EventType.AppCrashed, exceptionMsg, Environment.MachineName);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Following should work

```
[Event((int)EventType.AppCrashed, Channel = EventChannel.Admin, Message = "Unhandled exception occurred. Details: {0}", Keywords = EventKeywords.None, Level = EventLevel.Critical)]
private void UnhandledException(string exceptionMsg)
{
  WriteEvent(601, exceptionMsg, Environment.MachineName);
}
```

Do not forget to assign Enum Values during declaration.

```
enum EventType
{
 AppCrashed = 601
}
```

Comment: Cast is not good way for me. I'll use many event ids and I don't want cast it every time.  Is there any another way to do this? Maybe with using inheritance, can I inherit any class from Event attribute and do something with it?

Comment: EventAttribute is a sealed class, so inheritance would not be possible